# Can I delete anaconda-ks.cfg and openscap_data from root folder?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, anaconda, openscap

I just noticed that after every fresh CentOS 7 (7.2) installation I perform, there are two files created in the root folder (`/root`):

- `openscap_data` folder
- `anaconda-ks.cfg` file

As far as I understand the openscap_scanner is a vulnerability scanner that runs after installation and puts its scans in `/root/openscap_data`. I assume I can delete the folder since I have not use openscap (not intentionally). And `anaconda-ks.cfg` is the "installation template" that gets created by the GUI installer. Since it stores my hashed root password, I'm not sure if I should keep this file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed these are files created by the OS install ... if you don't need them you can delete them. If you open anaconda-ks.cfg will see the sequence of installation from partitions to packages install.

Comment: BTW don't delete the /root directory just the two files :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the hint. I just wanted to be sure.